# Rust not installing on ARM

Tags: rust

I recently tried to install Rust on my Raspberry Pi 3 using `curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh`. I encountered this error:

```
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf'
error: could not download file from 'https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml.sha256' to '/home/pi/.rustup/tmp/ieoxyuvmrrqhmbgn_file'
info: caused by: error during download
info: caused by: [1] Unsupported protocol (Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl)
```

I checked my `curl` with OpenSSL links and works fine. Also, tried other installation methods, crashed my RPi3 thrice.
Any help?

Comment: **How did you try to install Rust**? Additionally — *Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl* — does your libcurl have HTTP support?

Comment: yep, it works alright, and using `curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh `

Comment: Why do you think I downvoted? However, the downvote arrow says: *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*; presumably someone thinks your question fits that category.

Comment: oh not you. Sorry, also I cannot vote so I do not see the message

Comment: could have better worded the question....

Comment: I see that [you've filed an issue with rustup](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/issues/1066), wherein someone already pointed you to the [existing issue](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/issues/1051). Do you think that the rustup maintainers are lying to you? Do you think that we will know something that they don't? I'm unclear on what resolution you are looking for...

Comment: It didn't help me, tried everything, didn't work. You think I'm stupid?

Comment: No, not stupid; it's just *unclear* what you *have* done. We aren't mind readers. If you had "tried everything", then nothing we could suggest would help — there'd be nothing left to suggest. Therefore, it seems unlikely that you've tried everything. Someone on that thread suggests using `RUSTUP_USE_HYPER`; did you try that? If so, how would we know? The official [Rust installation page](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/install.html) offers [alternate installation methods](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/other-installers.html); did you try any of those? If so, how would we know?

Comment: People are [now reporting success with `RUSTUP_USE_HYPER`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/issues/1051#issuecomment-294255617).

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to install wtih the new minimal instruction on the Rust site for an ARMv7 Odroid XU4 running Debian Jessie and I guess the same goes for the Raspberry Pi.

I found the following preparatory steps necessary:
in .bashrc add:

```
export RUSTUP_USE_HYPER=1
export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH
```

and installed

```
sudo apt-get install curl linux-compiler-gcc-4.8-arm llvm clang-3.8
```

then
`curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh`
worked.

More detail on http://andrewufrank.blogspot.co.at/2017/05/rust-programming-language-on-arm-may.html